# Nonisomorphic groups with the same character tables, including power maps

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

It is known that two finite groups with the same complex character table are not necessarily isomorphic. The examples of smallest order are the quaternion group and the dihedral group of order $8$.

We can extend the character table by specifying the **power maps**. Given an element $x\in G$, we can calculate any $x^n$ up to conjugacy by following an element through its power maps one prime factor at a time.

We can define this because two conjugate elements raised to the same power will still be conjugate: $$\begin{align}x^n &= h^{-1}(g^{-1}xg)^nh\\ &= h^{-1}g^{-1}(x(gg^{-1}))^{n-1}xgh^{-1}\\&= h^{-1}g^{-1}x^{n}gh\end{align}$$$$, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, \forall x,g \in G,\exists h\in G $$

. Then the aforementioned groups of order $8$ have nonisomorphic power maps:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 Q_8 & 1A & 2A & 4A & 4B & 4C \\
2 & 1A & 1A &2A &2A &2A
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
D_{4} & 1A & 2A & 2B & 2C & 4A \\
2 & 1A & 1A & 1A &1A & 2A
\end{bmatrix}$$

I have checked every pair of groups with isomorphic character tables up to order $27$, and they have different power maps. I know that's not much, but I can't imagine stumbling into a counterexample and I'm sure an expert would have far more efficient tactics to find one.

The question:

> What are two non-isomorphic finite groups $G_1, G_2$ with isomorphic character tables, including power maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pairs of groups with this property are called *Brauer pairs*. The first examples were found by Dade. See [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869305004722) for some examples of order $p^5$ for primes $p \ge 5$.